# ViewComponent does not render on _Layout file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have added a ViewComponent  `<vc:my-profile-menu />` in the _Layout file. On the development computer, it displays correctly, but when I deploy it to the server, it does not render. In the source view, I can see the code as plain text. I use ViewComponents in other areas of the site and those work fine. I also tried to render using `@await Component.InvokeAsync("MyProfileMenu")`, but then the page crashed on the server. It rendered fine on the local computer. Any suggestions would be appreciated. The application is in dotnet 6.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem has resolved itself as it is no longer an issue without any changes in the code.